# ubuntu chown to var folder

Tags: ubuntu

help !  Accidentally changed permissions on all files in /var folder!

gave sudo chown username:username -R  /var

now not able to login 
showing couldnt update .ICEauthority /var/lib/gdm/.ICEauthority

KINDLY HELP ME OUT 
how to restore permission to root and login
ASAP

Comment: GAK! Unless you know a whole lotta UNIX you will be reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that come up in my mind would be to go to single user mode where you will log in as root user. Then you can change the ownership on files in /var as they should be, but it will be a little tricky.

If you are using GUI for log in to the sytem, try to press ctrl+f1 and log in directly as root, if it will work you do not need to go to single user mode.

I would try to switch to console first and log in as root to prevent from rebooting the server.

You can then give all files back root ownership, but not all files are owned by root, there are files of other users like mysql if you have, etc.

Comment: if give chown root /var -R in recovery mode and sudo reboot will the issue ICEauthority fix

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to login to the machine to fix the ownership, I think you have to reboot the machine using Ubuntu CD and run a root shell to fix ownership after mounting the needed partitions.

The difficult part is that not all files/folders are owned by root. So, you need to find another running machine and fix the ownership based on it. For a quick start you can change the ownership back to root. Then, change non-root ones.

To find similar files/folders on another machine which are owned by non-root users, you can use the following command:

```
$ find /var ! -user root
```

Comment: had given 
sudo chown username /var -R

Comment: so if give chown root /var -R in recovery mode and sudo reboot will the issue ICEauthority fix